# Save Value Returned in Either URI or Response to Test Context Using Cypress IO

Tags: javascript, npm, cypress

I want to create a variable for a key that is returned in the URI, and also in the xhr response.  I tried going the route of URI, since that seemed easiest, but not sure how to tell it to only save a portion of the URI, rather than the entire value.

```
.url().then(($url) => {
            const moveKey = $url.text(/someString.+?(?=\/)/);
            cy.log(moveKey);
        })
```

I also tried using `cy.route` and `cy.wait`, but wait always times out.

```
cy.server()
        .route('/overview').as('getMove')
        .wait('@getMove').then((xhr) => {
            const moveKey = xhr.move.key;
        })
```

url = https://app.com/move/xxxxxx/overview

Comment: If you want to extract key from the active location: can you try using `cy.location` (refer: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/location.html#Examples)

Comment: `cy.server()` cannot be chained further. Refer: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/server.html#Yields

Comment: @Sree.Bh Tried adding `cy` in front of `.route` and `.wait`, still timed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Srinu Kodi's suggestion I as able to figure this out using `match`.

```
.url().then(($url) => {
            const moveKey = $url.match(/someString.+?(?=\/)/);
            cy.log(moveKey);
        })
```

The log outputs an array with the key I needed.  Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with Cypress. It requires lil concepts on javascript strings. Please use below snippet and it works as per the requirement.

```
it('test', ()=>{
    cy.url().then(fullURL=>{
      fullURL = 'https://app.com/move/xxxxxx/overview';
      let arr = fullURL.substr(fullURL.indexOf('move')).split('/');
      let moveKey = arr[1];
      cy.log(moveKey);
    }
  )})
```

Comment: I'd remove the line `fullURL = 'https://app.com/move/xxxxxx/overview';`  The key is dynamic, so cannot be known ahead of time, and the variable has already been set when you typed `then(fullURL`